# Convert from UCS2 Little Endian to ANSI in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, character-encoding

In some tests I'm running at work, I have some automatically generated .htm files.  I've been trying all day to parse the data and bring it into excel.  I finally realized that the issue is that the files output by the lab equipment are encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian.  In order to read the file into a text stream, it needs to be ANSI or Unicode.

Is there a way that I can convert between the two encodings without using an external application?

Thanks.

Edit:
So I tried implementing a solution with StrConv as per Noodles's answer.  However, it doesn't seem to be working as I would expect.  Below is my code.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's not working?

```
Sub ParseReport()                                                               'Parses TX Compliance report generated by LeCroy Scope

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                          'Turn off screen updating until end of sub
    On Error Resume Next                                                        'ignore errors
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Set rStart = Range("A1")                                                    'set starting cell to A0
    sPath = Range("B3").Value & "\"                                             'set file path (pulled from cell B3)
    sPart = ActiveSheet.Name                                                    'set part name to be active sheet name
    sEnd = "<"                                                                  'set end string to "<" (used in for loops below to pull result values from file)

    For iVT = 0 To 24 Step 6                                                    'loop through all VT runs (hilighted in yellow in worksheet)

        For iPort = 0 To 4                                                      'loop through all ports within each VT parameter

            sVT = rStart.Offset(4, 1 + iVT).Value                               'get VT parameter for filename
            sPort = rStart.Offset(5, 1 + iVT + iPort).Value                     'get port information for filename
            sFileName = sPath & sPart & "_" & sPort & "_" & sVT & ".htm"        'set filename
            Set sFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, TristateTrue)   'open file in text stream as unicode
            sFileText = sFile.ReadAll                                           'parse entire file into string
            sAnsiFile = StrConv(sFileText, vbFromUnicode)                        'convert from unicode to system default
            File.Close                                                          'close text stream

            Debug.Print sFileText

            For iTest = 0 To 52                                                 'loop through each test run on part

                sTest = rStart.Offset(6 + iTest, 0).Value                       'get test name from worksheet
                iBegin = InStr(sFileText, sTest) + Len(sTest) + 28              'set beginning character index for string parsing
                iEnd = InStr(iBegin, sFileText, sEnd)                           'set ending character index for string parsing
                sValue = Mid(sFileText, iBegin, iEnd - iBegin)                  'extract result data from file text
                rTest.Offset(iTest, iVT + iPort + 1) = sValue                   'place result data in appropriate cell

            Next                                                                'next test
        Next                                                                    'next port
    Next                                                                        'next VT run

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                               'turn on screen updating

End Sub
```

Currently, the strings sFileText and sAnsiFile (which I ultimately want to parse and bring into the worksheet) is not being filled with the whole text from the .htm file.  When I run the code, the locals output for sFileText and sAnsiFile are as follows:

sFileText    : "ÿþ<    : Variant/String
sUniFile     : "?<     : Variant/String

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit2:
So big oversight on my part: I forgot that .htm files contain the encoding in the header.  The files I'm working with are UTF-16.  I'm not sure whether or not this makes a difference.

Thanks.

Edit3:
Alright, so I chose Noodles's answer, because he did answer my question.  However, it didn't solve my issue, mostly because I think I was asking the wrong question.  Anyway, in my comment below, I noted the fix that solved my issue (for some reason, adding "False" as an argument in the .OpenTextFile method made it work).  With this fix, the StrConv() function isn't actually needed.  Below is the updated code.

```
Sub ParseReport()                                                               'Parses TX Compliance report generated by LeCroy Scope

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                          'Turn off screen updating until end of sub
    On Error Resume Next                                                        'ignore errors
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Set rStart = Range("A1")                                                    'set starting cell to A0
    sPath = Range("B3").Value & "\"                                             'set file path (pulled from cell B3)
    sPart = ActiveSheet.Name                                                    'set part name to be active sheet name
    sEnd = "<"                                                                  'set end string to "<" (used in for loops below to pull result values from file)

    For iVT = 0 To 24 Step 6                                                    'loop through all VT runs (hilighted in yellow in worksheet)

        For iPort = 0 To 4                                                      'loop through all ports within each VT parameter

            sVT = rStart.Offset(4, 1 + iVT).Value                               'get VT parameter for filename
            sPort = rStart.Offset(5, 1 + iVT + iPort).Value                     'get port information for filename
            sFileName = sPath & sPart & "_" & sPort & "_" & sVT & ".htm"        'set filename
            Set sFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, False, TristateTrue)    'open file in text stream as unicode
            sFileText = sFile.ReadAll                                           'parse entire file into string
            File.Close                                                          'close text stream

            Debug.Print sFileText

            For iTest = 0 To 52                                                 'loop through each test run on part

                sTest = rStart.Offset(6 + iTest, 0).Value                       'get test name from worksheet
                iBegin = InStr(sFileText, sTest) + Len(sTest) + 28              'set beginning character index for string parsing
                iEnd = InStr(iBegin, sFileText, sEnd)                           'set ending character index for string parsing
                sValue = Mid(sFileText, iBegin, iEnd - iBegin)                  'extract result data from file text
                rTest.Offset(iTest, iVT + iPort + 1) = sValue                   'place result data in appropriate cell

            Next                                                                'next test
        Next                                                                    'next port
    Next                                                                        'next VT run

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                               'turn on screen updating

End Sub
```

Thanks to all those who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StrConv Function

Returns a Variant (String) converted as specified.

Syntax

```
StrConv(string, conversion, LCID)
```

The StrConv function syntax has these named arguments:

Part Description

**string** Required. String expression to be converted.

**conversion Required**. Integer. The sum of values specifying the type of conversion to perform.

**LCID Optional**. The LocaleID, if different than the system LocaleID. (The system LocaleID is the default.)

Settings

The conversion argument settings are:

Constant:  Value  -- Description

- `vbUpperCase`: 1 -- Converts the string to uppercase characters.
- `vbLowerCase`: 2 -- Converts the string to lowercase characters.
- `vbProperCase`: 3 -- Converts the first letter of every word in string to uppercase.
- `vbWide`: 4 -- Converts narrow (single-byte) characters in string to wide (double-byte) characters
- `vbNarrow`: 8 -- Converts wide (double-byte) characters in string to narrow (single-byte)  * characters
- `vbKatakana`: 16 --  Converts Hiragana characters in string to Katakana characters.
- `vbHiragana`: 32 --  Converts Katakana characters in string to Hiragana characters.
- `vbUnicode`: 64  -- Converts the string to Unicode using the default code page of the system.
- `vbFromUnicode`: 128 --  Converts the string from Unicode to the default code page of the system.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This looks like exactly what I need.  A quick question though: how do I know the default code page of the system?

Comment: So after messing around with the .OpenTextFile method, I tried adding in an argument for the "boolean" parameter, because I was creating files that didn't exist (bad news).  Anyway, adding a "False" in to the .OpenTextFile method seemed to solve my text stream problem.  Although, honestly, I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I lost my other ID so I'm a new noodles.

The reason your first code want working is it says

```
Set sFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, TristateTrue)
```

which means fname = **sFilename**, open mode = **ForReading**, CREATE = **-1 (TriStateTrue)**. **Optional format isn't specified**. Create takes True or False so you are specifing to create file if it doesn't exist and open as ANSI the default (I know it says ASCII but windows uses ANSI).

What you could have done is omit the argument (look for the extra comma).

```
Set sFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading, , TristateTrue)
```

I note you using this

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

So if you are interested in performance minimise dots (each dot is a lookup), especially in loops.

There are two ways. One is to set objects to the lowest object if you are going to access more than once.

eg (slower)

```
set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
msgbox xlapp.worksheets(0).name
```

(faster because you omitt a dot every time you use the object)

```
set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
set wsheet = xlapp.worksheets(0)
msgbox wsheet.name
```

The second way is `with`.
 You can only have one `with` active at a time.

This skips 100 lookups.

```
with wsheet
For x = 1 to 100
 msgbox .name
Next
end with
```

Comment: PS. UCS-2 is a older standard and was used up to Windows 2000. From Windows XP it's UTF-16. Difference is UCS-2 has 65,535 characters, one per code point. UTF-16 some code points are two nominal codepoints wide for really obsure characters (such as long dead languages). This supports zillions of characters where most are 16 bit but some are 32 bit.

Comment: So, when I used TristateTrue in an attempt to specify format, it was actually reading that value into the boolean parameter?  

Also, as far as minimizing dots goes: I'm not terribly concerned with performance, I just don't like my screen constantly updating.  It's more an aesthetic than anything else.

Thanks again!